# Interlocking plastic, rubber, or foam product that can be cut to size?

Tags: material-selection, plastic, material-identification

Would you know if there's some sort of interlocking plastic (or other material) mats that can be cut to any size and which is less than 1 inch (2.5cm) thick? Ideally probably 1 - 1.5cm thickness.

I'm trying to use this to hold together hobby electronics/robotics parts. Something like this:

[image]

I took an online class from a Russian instructor on robotics, and in Russia they sell this in their version of one of the electronics/robotics stores called Amperka (our version is called Arduino). However, it hasn't caught on in Western stores yet. I can't easily order it from Russia because of differences in the types of payment/banks they use, not to mention the shipping cost and time.

I've been trying to search for this online but I can't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: This one is bugging me because you would think there would be _something_ available. Do you intend to reuse these "panels"?. I have two suggestions. Plastic mesh that is used for yarn could be cut to shape. However most of the common ones would not make for a firm container. Others are advertised as stiff but I have no experience. The other thing I thought of would be to just cut acrylic to shape with a knife or saw. It would be easy to do with minimal tools and you could glue or even melt them together. Would not be interlocking or as easy to disassemble though.

Comment: @Matt Thank you much. It would be nice to be able to reuse it but it's not an absolute necessity assuming that these materials don't cost too much. I am not very familiar with some of the things that you mentioned. If you have any links that would be awesome.

Comment: What are your requirements for you ideal material?

Comment: @Matt  just something that will stay together using that interlocking pattern (like in the picture) and which I could cut with a pair of heavy duty kitchen scissors if it's not the right size. I'm thinking something that's kind of a foam or plastic but I'm not really sure as I am a total amateur here. Many thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Matt's suggestion of what is called plastic mesh is likely to be the best find.

[image: plastic mesh]

The image above shows a typical product known as [7 mesh plastic canvas](https://www.consumercrafts.com/store/details/catalog/basics-plastic-canvas/33418-1), for 7 holes per inch and lists as being 13.5 by 10.5 inches without a thickness reference. I've seen this material in the past and found it to be about 2 mm, perhaps slightly thicker.

Another site has similar material, a wide selection, including some [5 mesh plastic canvas](http://www.everythingplasticcanvas.com/plastic-canvas-5-mesh-1325-x-22-mrp-p20123.aspx?k2=y2). That particular product must have rather large openings, allowing for an approximate 5 mm between holes! As such, it's likely to be stiffer as well.